# Changing color according to attribute from another layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, color

I have township polygons on a first layer and landmark points on a second layer.

I would like change the color of each township polygons when landmarks points are missing.

I can already select one polygon according its code think to the following script :

```
import processing
layer = processing.getObject('township')
query = '"code" = 99 '
selection =    layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

I can also change the color of all polygons :

```
symbols = layer.rendererV2().symbols()
symbol = symbols[0]
symbol.setColor(QColor("orange"))
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)
```

The attribute table of landmark layer contains the numero , geometry and township's code for each mark. Unfortanutaly some geometries are missing !

I need help to make a final script on PyQgis to change the color of only township polygons without landmarks geometry.